# How to consolidate these functions into a generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a few functions...

```
@Override
public List<ContentType> findAllContentTypes() {
    return this.emf.createEntityManager()
                   .createNamedQuery("ContentType.findAll", ContentType.class)
                   .getResultList();
}

@Override
public List<Status> findAllStatus() {
    return this.emf.createEntityManager()
                   .createNamedQuery("Status.findAll", Status.class)
                   .getResultList();
}
```

In fact I have about 12 of these that get all kinds of different things.  I'd like to take these functions and make a single generic function to replace all of these.

The best way I can think to do this would be to do something like `findAll("Language")`.  I started doing...

```
public List<T> findAll(String objectName) {
    return this.emf.createEntityManager()
                   .createNamedQuery(objectName+".findAll", objectName)
                   .getResultList();
}
```

The problem (other than my IDE throwing a fit with not knowing what to do with `T`) is that I'm not sure how to take that string and pass it in place of `ContentType.class`.

What am I missing that's preventing Netbeans from recognizing `T`?

Will `objectName` work the way I'm passing it as a second parameter to `createNamedQuery()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your method as generic, by adding the type parameter list (`<T>` in this case) before the method return type. Then just pass in the class object of the right type as a parameter:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    return this.emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery(
            clazz.getSimpleName()+".findAll", clazz).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need to have `public <T> List<T>` and not just `public List<T>` ?

Comment: Because you need to indicate what kind of type is `<T>`, you could force T to extends another klass like this: `<T extends Number>`. By declaring `<T>` you indicate that it can be of any type that extends Object (ie, all types)

Comment: Gotcha!  Also, `contentDao.findAll("User")` or `contentDao.findAll(new User())` doesn't seem to be what this function is looking for...

Comment: @Webnet No, you should call `contentDao.findAll(User.class)`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - Thanks!!  That did it!! What does `User.class` pass that `User` doesn't?

Comment: @Webnet, User.class is the *class token* for this class, which can be used runtime to access all known information about this class. Including its name, members, superclass(es), etc. `new User()` is an instance of this class, which contains none of this meta-information directly. `"User"` is a String which happens to be the simple (unqualified) name of a class, but for the runtime system it is not at all obvious, and not even unique by itself (without full package name).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> klass) {
    return this.emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery(klass.getSimpleName()+".findAll", klass).getResultList();
}
```